# iTunes (TestFlight) - Uploaded and Visible in Activity but not available in TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, testflight, appcelerator-titanium

[image]

I am extremely confused on trying to fix this different kind of Issue faced in iTunes. Actually I am Using **Appcelerator** to develop and build the Application. I had successfully get the .ipa file from the Appcelerator and by using the **Application Loader** I am uploading the App to the iTunes. Once my Upload is completed in iTunes my App gets visible in Activity tab that Which I had mentioned in the first Image as well as I had received the mail that "*The App has been successfully moved to the iTunes and Ready for move to Testflight*". In TestFlight Initially under the version number build is available with the tabular column showing the alert of **Missing Compliances**, then for the first question I gave **"NO"** and then gave start Internal testing, after this my build is no longer available in Testflight and then seems to be the second Image that I had Attached. I had a cross check with my distribution profile , Certificate and App ID that's all fine. I had been searching in many forums to fix this Issue. Can anyone faced this Issue? Please assist me on this Issue, I had been struggling for a week.

Comment: You better ask it to [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ohk Thanks Zico...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had fixed the Issue by changing my provisioning profile from Adhoc Distribution profile to AppStore Distribution Profile and then take a build and upload it via Organiser of xCode. Then the App details are visible in Test flight.